# Java - JFrame not updating when called

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

a little background before i begin, what i'm doing is making a chess game, i have everything working the way i want apart from the game's score. I have a method in a class called `Board` and whitin that class i have a method called `updateScore()`.

```
private void updateScore(){
            int whitePawn = 0;              int blackPawn = 0;
            int whiteKnight = 0;            int blackKnight = 0;
            int whiteBishop = 0;            int blackBishop = 0;
            int whiteCastle = 0;            int blackCastle = 0;
            int whiteQueen = 0;             int blackQueen = 0;
            int whiteKing = 0;              int blackKing = 0;

            for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){     //Checks through the board to see what pieces are on it.
                    for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++){
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 11){
                            whitePawn++;    //increments the vales how many of a certain pieces are on the board.
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 12){
                            whiteCastle++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 13){
                            whiteKnight++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 14){
                            whiteBishop++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 15){
                            whiteQueen++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 16){
                            whiteKing++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 21){
                            blackPawn++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 22){
                            blackCastle++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 23){
                            blackKnight++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 24){
                            blackBishop++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 25){
                            blackQueen++;
                    }
                    if(gameBoard[k][l] == 26){
                            blackKing++;
                    }
                    }

            }

            if(whiteKing == 0){     //No white king? Checkmate.
                    checkMate(1);
            }
            else if(blackKing == 0){ //No black king? Checkmate.
                    checkMate(2);
            }

            score = new Scores();
            score.showScores(whitePawn, blackPawn);
    }
```

I also have another class called `Scores` which initializes another JFrame to show the game score like so:

[image: Game board ans score window]

Here is the scores class as follows:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Scores extends JFrame{

    private int width = 300;
    private int height = 400;
    int whitePawn = 0;
    int blackPawn = 0;

    public Scores(){

        int a = this.getWidth();
        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle("Chess - Scores");
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon("imgs/chess-icon.png").getImage());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(a+25,50);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(p);

        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        Box horizontalBox;
        //showScores(whitePawn, blackPawn);

    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void showScores(int wp, int bp){
        whitePawn = wp;
        blackPawn = bp;
        JLabel white_pawn = new JLabel("White Pawn: "+wp+" ", JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel black_pawn = new JLabel("White Pawn: "+bp+" ", JLabel.CENTER);

        add(white_pawn, Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(9, 0)));
        add(black_pawn, Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(9, 0)));
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

But the problem occurring is that the window never updates when the method is called? Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Can you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Where's the `getContentPane()` method?

Comment: In my Scores class constructor

Answer (score 2):

You do realize that `JFrame` has no `paintComponent` method right? So you're not overriding anything. Should use a `JPanel` if you want to use `paintComponent`

Also, is it possible this is a scope issue? Are any other components reliant on the `whitePawn, whiteKing, etc` variables? Because all of them are locally scoped. The variables will always start at 0 no matter how many times you call the method

Comment: Hmm, i didn't think of that. The method updateScore() in my board class is public in any case

Comment: @CianGallaghar honestly I have no idea what your problem is. I have to code to run and nothing to test. I'm just looking for possible problems that may not even be causing a problem for you. I really sugggest trying to put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You might even get lucky an figure it out for yourself while in the processs. It happens. This seems to be a program that's reliant on many factors. So without being able to run something and test it, its hard to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
super.paintComponent's'(g);
```

Looks like you have a typo. Get rid of the "s" in paintComponent().

Answer (score 0):

In your Scores.showScores method use

```
getContentPane().add()
```

insted of just calling add